# Circular dependencies with observables

Tags: javascript, monads, reactive-programming, mostjs

I have a number of streams that have circular dependencies.

```
import input from './input'

const streamA = input.thru( someUsageOf_streamC );
const streamB = input.thru( someOtherUsageOf_streamC );
const streamC = most.merge(
                    streamA.constant('A'),
                    streamB.constant('B'),
                );
```

The functions passed to `.thru(...)` take the stream and apply some combination of operators such as `.filter()`, `.map()`, `.until()` but, notably (see below for why), `.delay()`.

These are things I've tried already:

### Method 1

```
const someUsageOf_StreamC = streamX =>
    streamX.sample( (x,c) => [x,c], streamX, streamC )
           .filter( ([x,c]) => c === 'something' )
           .map( ([x,c]) => x );
```

The problem here is you have to pass the streams to sample upfront but `streamC` can't be declared before `streamA` and `streamB`.

### Method 2 (or 1.1)

```
import { subject } from 'most-subject'

const streamC = subject();

const streamA = ...;
const streamB = ...;
const streamC_proxy = most.merge( /* ...as above... */ );

streamC_proxy.subscribe( streamC );
```

This method builds on Method 1, but just proxies the events from `streamC_proxy` into `streamC` which can be declared beforehand using [most-subject](https://github.com/mostjs-community/subject).

I think this actually works, but it's not testable using [most-test](https://github.com/mostjs-community/most-test) (it requires using its own scheduler but `.subscribe()`/`.observe()` implicitly use the `defaultScheduler`). As I said, I use `.delay()` and waiting seconds/minutes for tests to run - using the default scheduler - is not feasible.

### Method 3

```
import hold from '@most/hold'

const someUsageOf_StreamC = streamX =>
    streamX.flatMap( x => streamC.take(1) // @most/hold
                                 .filter( c => c === 'something' )
                                 .constant(x) )
           .multicast();

const streamA = ...;
const streamB = ...;
const streamC = most.merge( ... ).thru( hold );
```

Apart from this code being far from ideal, it *should* work. [But it doesn't](https://github.com/mostjs/hold/issues/11) :(

### Question

Can this be done in a testable manner?

Comment: reminds me of how cycle js works. I believe they provide a dummy value to circumvent the circular dependency. The creator has an egghead io course describing how the framework works - I believe this is the lesson where this is discussed https://egghead.io/lessons/rxjs-use-the-cycle-js-run-function